# how to create SSH server in namespaces?

Tags: networking, ssh, namespaces, macvlan

I created two namespace say namespace_A and namespace_B.

`ip netns add namespace_A`
`ip netns add namespace_B`

then created macvlan to each namespaces

`ip link add macvlan_A link wlo1 type macvlan mode bridge`

`ip link set macvlan_A netns namespace_A`

`ip netns exec namespace_A ifconfig macvlan_A 10.0.0.1`

and done the same thing with namespace_B with macvlan_B and ip is 10.0.0.2
Now i want to create SSH server in both the namespace and assign them with some port and also transfer file between namespace using SSH server.
but i am not able to understand how can i create server in that namespace and send file between the both namespaces? Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Start the ssh server in each name space:

```
ip netns exec namespace_A sshd -o PidFile=/run/sshd-namespace_A.pid
ip netns exec namespace_B sshd -o PidFile=/run/sshd-namespace_B.pid
```

more information here:
https://blog.bofh.it/debian/id_446